# Convert Custom Datatype to String

Tags: haskell

If I have three data types named `Expr`, `Op` and `Fu` like this.

```
data Expr = Num Double
          | X
          | Operator Op Expr Expr
          | Function Fu Expr
          deriving (Eq)

data Op = Add | Mul
        deriving (Eq)

data Fu = Sin | Cos
        deriving (Eq)
```

What I am supposed to do is later create an expression based on the datatype. For example

```
let anExpr = Add (Num 3.0) (Num 4.0)
```

And than print out the corresponding expression, in this case it should just be "3.0+4.0".

The problem I am facing is to create another type or data type to recognize if it is an addition or multiplication symbol it is supposed to print out. What I would like to do is something like this in pseudo code

```
printOut (Num n) = show n
printOut X = "x"
printOut (Op a b) = printOut a ++ 'printOutRightOp' ++ printOut b
printOut (Fu a) = 'printOutRightFu' ++ printOut a
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: But `Op` and `Fu` in your `Expr` are the **names of the constructors**.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: @Salviati You just have a typo at the beginning that should read "if I have three data types **Expr**, Op, and Fu"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **can not write references to types as constructor name**. In your code:

```
data Expr = Num Double
          | X
          | Op Expr Expr
          | Fu Expr
          deriving (Eq)
```

`Op` and `Fu` are the **names of the constructors**. Haskell considers the fact that there is a type with the same name, just a coincidence. You have to **add the type of operator/function as first argument**. So:

```
data Expr = Num Double
          | X
          | Op Op Expr Expr
          | Fu Fu Expr
          deriving (Eq)
```

Now the second `Op` and `Fu` specify the types of the first parameters.

Now you thus have to replace your:

```
let anExpr = Add (Num 3.0) (Num 4.0)
```

with:

```
let anExpr = Op Add (Num 3.0) (Num 4.0)
```

Based on that, we can define some *helper* functions:

```
showOp :: Op -> String
showOp Add = "+"
showOp Mul = "*"

showFu :: Fu -> String
showFu Sin = "sin"
showFu Cos = "cos"
```

Now we can use these helper functions when we define our `showExpr` (I would not call it `printOut`, since the function does *not* print something, it only generates a string, you can do whatever you want with that string).

```
showExpr :: Expr -> String
showExpr (Num n) = show n
showExpr X = "x"
showExpr (Op o a b) = '(' : showExpr a ++ ')' : showOp o ++ '(' : showExpr b ++ ")"
showExpr (Fu f a) = showFu f ++ '(' : showExpr a ++ ")"
```

For example:

```
*Main> showExpr (Op Add (Num 3.0) (Num 4.0))
"(3.0)+(4.0)"
*Main> showExpr (Op Add (Num 3.0) (Fu Sin (Num 4.0)))
"(3.0)+(sin(4.0))"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you pattern match, you need to match on the constructor you passed in. In your example, an `Expr` can have an `Operator` constructor that contains the relevant information to print:

```
printOut (Num n) = show n
printOut X = "x"
printOut (Operator op a b) = printOut a ++ printOp op ++ printOut b
printOut (Function fu a) = printFun fu ++ printOut a
```

Now you just define additional pattern matches for your operators and functions:

```
printOp Add = "+"
printOp Mul = "x"

printFun Sin = "Sin"
printFun Cos = "Cos"
```

In addition to what @WillemVanOnsem wrote, you actually aren't printing anything to the screen with these "print" functions. Instead, you are converting them from your datatype to a string. There is a common typeclass that does that called [`Show`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show). You could also just create instances of show for your types, and use that function to display them instead:

```
instance Show Fu where 
  show Sin = "Sin"
  show Cos = "Cos"
```

and then use `show` instead:

```
printOut (Function fu a) = show fu ++ printOut a
```

When you have a simple instance of `show`, you can also just have it derived automatically for you using the same syntax as you are using for deriving `Eq`:

```
data Fu = Sin | Cos
        deriving (Show, Eq)
```

---

To deal with creating an instance of `Expr`, again you use the various *constructors* to do so:

```
let anExpr = Operator Add (Num 3.0) (Num 4.0)
```

Comment: Ty so much, really feel data types is a lot clearer now. It really is a pain in the ass before it is understood.

Comment: Show instances should typically print valid Haskell code that could be read back as the same value by a reasonable Read instance. When you want to print the data in a different format, as here, it's better to define a separate function for it than to repurpose Show.

Comment: @amalloy Good point. You can still create a custom `read` instance to satisfy that `read . show == id`, but in this case you probably don't want that for the operators. Maybe the `Fu` type is a better example here.

Comment: No, the strings you output with this answer cannot possibly be read back in such that `read . show == id` because they are ambiguous. What is "1+1+1"? It could be `(Operator Add 1 (Operator Add 1 1))` or `(Operator Add (Operator Add 1 1) 1)`.

Comment: @amalloy Notice that my example is not an instance of `show` for `Expr`, only `Op`. You wouldn't have a read for "1+1+1" you'd only have an instance for "+". My suggestion in the previous comment was just for a show instance for `Fu` so that instead of using `printFun Sin = "Sin"` you have `show Sin = "Sin"` or an automated deriving. These smaller datatypes make perfect sense to have shows and reads.

Comment: Ah, I indeed didn't notice that. I now agree this is an admissible `Show` instance, although I still don't see the value in it compared to using a different function.

Comment: Since the OP is new to haskell, I just wanted to through the idea of a typeclass out there, and maybe point them to `Show` if they hadn't seen it before. It's not necessarily better, just another way to skin the cat.